# Virtual Memory allocation without Physical Memory allocation

Tags: c, linux, memory, virtual, kernel

I'm working on a Linux kernel project and i need to find a way to allocate Virtual Memory without allocating Physical Memory. For example if I use this :

```
char* buffer = my_virtual_mem_malloc(sizeof(char) * 512);
```

my_virtual_mem_malloc is a new SYSCALL implemented by my kernel module. All data written on this buffer is stocked on file or on other server by using socket (not on Physical Memory). So to complete this job, i need to request Virtual Memory and get access to the vm_area_struct structure to redefine vm_ops struct.

Do you have any ideas about this ?

thx

Comment: `sizeof(char)` is guaranteed to be 1 by the C language standard.

Comment: of course, but is not the problem

Answer (score 3):

This is not architecturally possible. You can create vm areas that have a writeback routine that copies data somewhere, but at some level, you must allocate physical pages to be written to.

If you're okay with that, you can simply write a [FUSE driver](http://fuse.sourceforge.net/), mount it somewhere, and mmap a file from it. If you're not, then you'll have to just `write()`, because redirecting writes without allocating a physical page *at all* is not supported by the x86, at the very least.

Comment: Well.. you *could* leave the page as unmapped, then in the page fault handler inspect the faulting instruction and emulate it.  But that'd be awfully slow, and require a full instruction decoder.

Comment: so it could be possible by handling Page fault exception to cancel it when it appear for virtual address used by my modified malloc ?

Comment: @Corvus, caf's idea is theoretically possible but a _terrible_ idea. It will slow accesses by a factor of a thousand, _at least_.

Comment: I/O MMU allows you to write directly to the device buffer without any intermediate memory, but I wouldn't go for this approach.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few approaches to this problem, but most of them require you to first write to an intermediate memory.

## Network File System (NFS)

The easiest approach is simply to have the server open some sort of a shared file system such as [NFS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_File_System) and using [`mmap()`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mmap) to map a remote file to a memory address. Then, writing to that address will actually write the OS's page cache, wich will eventually be written to the remote file when the page cache is full or after predefined system timeout.

## Distributed Shared Memory (DSM)

An alternative approach is using [DSM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distributed_shared_memory) with a very small cache size.

> In computer science, distributed shared memory (DSM) is a form of memory architecture where physically separated memories can be addressed as one logically shared address space.
>
> [...] Software DSM systems can be implemented in an operating system, or as a programming library and can be thought of as extensions of the underlying virtual memory architecture. When implemented in the operating system, such systems are transparent to the developer; which means that the underlying distributed memory is completely hidden from the users.

It means that each virtual address is *logically* mapped to a virtual address on a remote machine and writing to it will do the following: (a) receive the page from the remote machine and gain exclusive access. (b) update the page data. (c) release the page and send it back to the remote machine when it reads it again.

On typical DSM implementation, (c) will only happen when the remote machine will read the data again, but you might start from existing DSM implementation and change the behavior so that the data is sent once the local machine page cache is full.

## I/O MMU

> [...] the IOMMU maps device-visible virtual addresses (also called device addresses or I/O addresses in this context) to physical addresses.

This basically means to write directly to the network device buffer, which is actually implementing an alternative driver for that device.
Such approach seems the most complicated and I don't see any benefit from that approach.

This approach is actually not using any intermediate memory but is definitely not recommended unless the system has a heavy realtime requirement.